# More elegant way of defining numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking for a more elegant/neat way to create a `numpy` array of the numbers `[1e-1, 2e-1, 3e-1, ..., 1e0, 2e0, 3e0, ..., 1e3, 2e3, 3e3, ..., 8e3, 9e3, 1e4]`

The best I could come up with was

```
a = np.arange(9)+1
b = np.array([a*10**-1, a*10**0, a*10**1, a*10**2, a*10**3]).flatten()
b = np.append(b, 10000)

In [84]: b
Out[84]: 
array([  1.00000000e-01,   2.00000000e-01,   3.00000000e-01,
         4.00000000e-01,   5.00000000e-01,   6.00000000e-01,
         7.00000000e-01,   8.00000000e-01,   9.00000000e-01,
         1.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00,
         4.00000000e+00,   5.00000000e+00,   6.00000000e+00,
         7.00000000e+00,   8.00000000e+00,   9.00000000e+00,
         1.00000000e+01,   2.00000000e+01,   3.00000000e+01,
         4.00000000e+01,   5.00000000e+01,   6.00000000e+01,
         7.00000000e+01,   8.00000000e+01,   9.00000000e+01,
         1.00000000e+02,   2.00000000e+02,   3.00000000e+02,
         4.00000000e+02,   5.00000000e+02,   6.00000000e+02,
         7.00000000e+02,   8.00000000e+02,   9.00000000e+02,
         1.00000000e+03,   2.00000000e+03,   3.00000000e+03,
         4.00000000e+03,   5.00000000e+03,   6.00000000e+03,
         7.00000000e+03,   8.00000000e+03,   9.00000000e+03,
         1.00000000e+04])
```

Comment: You have some duplicate values in that array (1e0, 1e1, 1e2, 1e3) - is that desired, or not?

Comment: @jasonharper It is not, thanks for pointing that out. Edits made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass a list comprehension to `np.array` and then slice off what you don't need.

```
np.array([x*(10**y) for y in range(-1,5)  for x in range(1,10)])[:-8]

array([  1.00000000e-01,   2.00000000e-01,   3.00000000e-01,
         4.00000000e-01,   5.00000000e-01,   6.00000000e-01,
         7.00000000e-01,   8.00000000e-01,   9.00000000e-01,
         1.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00,
         4.00000000e+00,   5.00000000e+00,   6.00000000e+00,
         7.00000000e+00,   8.00000000e+00,   9.00000000e+00,
         1.00000000e+01,   2.00000000e+01,   3.00000000e+01,
         4.00000000e+01,   5.00000000e+01,   6.00000000e+01,
         7.00000000e+01,   8.00000000e+01,   9.00000000e+01,
         1.00000000e+02,   2.00000000e+02,   3.00000000e+02,
         4.00000000e+02,   5.00000000e+02,   6.00000000e+02,
         7.00000000e+02,   8.00000000e+02,   9.00000000e+02,
         1.00000000e+03,   2.00000000e+03,   3.00000000e+03,
         4.00000000e+03,   5.00000000e+03,   6.00000000e+03,
         7.00000000e+03,   8.00000000e+03,   9.00000000e+03,
         1.00000000e+04])
```

---

Or if you want to do it all in numpy, you can use matrix multiplication, flatten with `ravel`, and then slice off the end.

```
np.ravel(np.power(10.0, np.arange(-1,5))[:,np.newaxis]*np.arange(1,10))[:-8]

array([  1.00000000e-01,   2.00000000e-01,   3.00000000e-01,
         4.00000000e-01,   5.00000000e-01,   6.00000000e-01,
         7.00000000e-01,   8.00000000e-01,   9.00000000e-01,
         1.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00,
         4.00000000e+00,   5.00000000e+00,   6.00000000e+00,
         7.00000000e+00,   8.00000000e+00,   9.00000000e+00,
         1.00000000e+01,   2.00000000e+01,   3.00000000e+01,
         4.00000000e+01,   5.00000000e+01,   6.00000000e+01,
         7.00000000e+01,   8.00000000e+01,   9.00000000e+01,
         1.00000000e+02,   2.00000000e+02,   3.00000000e+02,
         4.00000000e+02,   5.00000000e+02,   6.00000000e+02,
         7.00000000e+02,   8.00000000e+02,   9.00000000e+02,
         1.00000000e+03,   2.00000000e+03,   3.00000000e+03,
         4.00000000e+03,   5.00000000e+03,   6.00000000e+03,
         7.00000000e+03,   8.00000000e+03,   9.00000000e+03,
         1.00000000e+04])
```

Comment: Perhaps slice before creating the array `np.array([x*(10**y) for y in range(-1,5)  for x in range(1,10)][:-8])` (although I'm not sure which is more efficient).

Answer (score 3):

```
np.array([x * 10**y for y in range(-1,4) for x in range(1,10)] + [1e4])
```

Answer (score 2):

One could use [`numpy.fromfunction()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html).

```
import numpy as np
a = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: (i+1)*10**(j-1), (9, 6)).T.flatten()[:-8]
```

which prints

```
[  1.00000000e-01   2.00000000e-01   3.00000000e-01   4.00000000e-01
   5.00000000e-01   6.00000000e-01   7.00000000e-01   8.00000000e-01
   9.00000000e-01   1.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00   3.00000000e+00
   4.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+00   6.00000000e+00   7.00000000e+00
   8.00000000e+00   9.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+01   2.00000000e+01
   3.00000000e+01   4.00000000e+01   5.00000000e+01   6.00000000e+01
   7.00000000e+01   8.00000000e+01   9.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+02
   2.00000000e+02   3.00000000e+02   4.00000000e+02   5.00000000e+02
   6.00000000e+02   7.00000000e+02   8.00000000e+02   9.00000000e+02
   1.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+03   3.00000000e+03   4.00000000e+03
   5.00000000e+03   6.00000000e+03   7.00000000e+03   8.00000000e+03
   9.00000000e+03   1.00000000e+04]
```

The advantage is that this is pure numpy and should therefore be highly efficient compared to any list comprehension techniques.

Another pure numpy method would be to use the outer product of the the logarithmic array from 1e-1 to 1e4 and the linear array from 1 to 9.

```
a = np.outer(np.logspace(-1, 4,6),np.arange(1, 10)).flatten()[:-8]
```

Answer (score 1):

shorter :

```
(10**(np.arange(37)//(37/4.))).cumsum()
```